# Express API: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: node.js, express

I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the answers served my case.
I keep getting this error even though I send a response to client only once. Please could anyone point to me what I'm missing? I appreciate any help. Here is my router code:

```
router.get("/trainers/:page/:limit", verifyToken, (req, res) => {

  const numPerPage = req.params.limit; // number of items per page
  const page = req.params.page;
  let result; //final object to be sent to client

  connection.query("Select count(*) as totalCount from trainers", (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500).json({error: err})
    }
    var totalCount = rows[0].totalCount;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / numPerPage);

    connection.query("SELECT id FROM trainers LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", [numPerPage, (page-1) * numPerPage], (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500).json({error: err})
      } else {
        result = { rows, numPages }
        res.json()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

here is the error log:

throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at Query. (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/routes/admin/trainers.js:53:36)
    at Query. (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/diego/Documents/DT Personal Training App/express-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Comment: Can you please paste the error logs as well?

Comment: sure, I've just updated the question with the error log. Thanks

Comment: `/routes/admin/trainers.js:53`  which line is it?

Comment: in the second query fuction, this line: ' return res.sendStatus(500).json({error: err}) '

Comment: can You do `console.log([numPerPage, (page-1) * numPerPage])` before calling query?

Comment: Yes can you try using res.status(500); res.json({error: err})

Comment: @num8er i did, the result is: [ '2', 0 ]

Comment: replace: `return res.sendStatus(500).json({error: err})` to `return res.status(500).json({error: err})`  I suspect `sendStatus` is sending headers and closing connection before sending `content-type` headers (for `json` method)

Comment: @num8er i'm getting this result: says its syntax error:

"error": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2' OFFSET 0' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "SELECT id FROM trainers LIMIT '2' OFFSET 0"
    }

Comment: Code looks ok, can you put the code from `verifyToken`. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Ah so the main error for which the question was raised is resolved. It was because of using setStatus and res.json together

Comment: `const numPerPage = parseInt(req.params.limit); const page = parseInt(req.params.page);`

Comment: @Owner got it. thanks very much.

Comment: @num8er this fixes the other error. thanks very much guys.

Comment: btw, instead of giving to client what happened it's better to log it and return empty response: `console.error(err); return res.status(500).end();` for security reasons. or use sentry service and get alerts to email: `Sentry.captureException(err); return res.status(500).end()`

Comment: @num8er makes sense. thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: @Diego https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/capturing/?platform=javascript

Comment: @num8er cheers for this link :)

Comment: @num8er by the way if you would like to post the answer for the question so that other people can easily find the solution, feel free to do so and i will accept that. thanks

Comment: @Diego it's very simple question to put answer, so feel free do Yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendStatus)

```
res.sendStatus(500) // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
```

so you need to use `res.status(500).json({error: err})` to avoid this error :)